# Test function generates different result each time using same inputs

Tags: php, r, unit-testing, testing, command-line

I have following test function:

```
class LinearRegressionTest extends TestCase {
    public function testR(): void {
        self::assertEquals( 10, LinearRegression::r() );
    }

}
```

and corresponding function, where I use library php-r (https://github.com/kachkaev/php-r):

```
use Kachkaev\PHPR\RCore;
use Kachkaev\PHPR\Engine\CommandLineREngine;

class LinearRegression {
    public static function r(): string {
        $r = new RCore( new CommandLineREngine( '/usr/lib/R/bin/R' ) );
        $rProcess = $r->createInteractiveProcess();
        $rProcess->start();

        $rProcess->write( 'x <- 5' );
        $rProcess->write( 'y <- 5' );
        $rProcess->write( 'y + x' );

        return $rProcess->getAllResult();
    }
}
```

I am really confused: when I run the test, sometimes I get correct result (test passed), but sometimes the test does not finnish (like some while cyklus??).

My question is why the same code finnish with different results? And how can I fix that?